# Why HTML5 syntax social plugins won't render if on FB.init xfbml property set to false?

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-javascript-sdk, xfbml

I have some HTML5 code to embed facebook social plugins.

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="some URL" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

When calling FB.init method of facebook JavaScript SDK with xfbml set to false thous plugins won't render.

```
FB.init({
      appId      : '{your-app-id}',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : false
    });
```

I can't understand why is it happens as I'm not using the XFBML notation.

Comment: The actual code where you use the data attributes would be helpful

Comment: Also, have you confirmed fb doesn't strip those out?

Comment: _“as I'm not using the XFBML notation”_ – that doesn’t matter, you are using _one_ of the methods of embedding that requires the JS SDK to _parse_ your document for specific tags, and `XFBML: true` tells it to do that – so it is _required_ even if you are using what Facebook calls the “HTML5” version of the social plugins.

Comment: @Anthony didn't understand what did you meant by "data attributes"

Comment: The only thing in your example HTML that is html5 specific is the use of data-* attributes, so if the plugins aren't working, it is either because these data attributes are being dropped or because your code is not handling them correctly. So before we can postulate blindly on what fb *might* be doing, we should verify that the problem isn't in your code.

Answer (score -1):

The first glance hints you should include a version number. I use `version: 'v2.1'`. Also, 
I am getting a doubt that you didn't include `{your_app_id}` with your real app_id...